# MVC4: ViewModel is empty on [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, viewmodel

I'm trying to make a simple news system in MVC4. I'm very new at it, and I have a simple News base class that looks like this:

NewsPost:

```
public class NewsPost
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual string Content { get; set; }
}
```

It's then attached to a category class like so:

**NewsCategory**:

```
public class NewsCategory
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<NewsPost> NewsPosts { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a controller for creating these NewsPosts:

**NewsController**:

```
private readonly INewMvcSiteDataSource _db;

public NewsController(INewMvcSiteDataSource db)
{
    _db = db;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CreateNewsViewModel();

    model.Categories = new SelectList(_db.NewsCategories, "Id", "Name");

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateNewsViewModel newsModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(newsModel.SelectedCategories.Single(f => f.Selected).Value);
    }
    return View(newsModel);
}
```

And lastly, to facilitate with creating the NewsPost, I use a CreateNewsViewModel, like so:

**CreateNewsViewModel**:

```
public class CreateNewsViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
    public SelectList SelectedCategories { get; set; }
}
```

My view looks like this:

**Create.cshtml**:

```
@model NewMvcSite.Models.CreateNewsViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreateNewsViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subject)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categories)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categories, Model.SelectedCategories)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

For some reason, my viewmodel isn't returned when I click the submit button to create the newspost, and since there is no parameterless constructor for [HttpPost] Create action, it fails with *"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."*

I've been trying going through other posts here stating the same problem, but I fail to see the connection between what they are doing and what I am doing. I hope there is someone out there who can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to change the ViewModel to this:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
public int SelectedCategoryId { get; set; }
```

I changed the controller to:

```
var model = new CreateNewsViewModel
                {
                    Categories = new SelectList(_db.NewsCategories, "Id", "Name")
                };
```

And changed View to this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCategoryId, Model.Categories)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select category from drop down list, first of all you should add property to your model to hold Id of selected category. Something like this (property **Category**):

```
public class CreateNewsViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
        public SelectList SelectedCategories { get; set; }
        public int Category { get; set; }
    }
```

after that, you should change code to filling **model.Category** to this:

```
model.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Name", model.Category);
```

and than, in your view, editor for Category should look like this:

```
    <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.Categories);


 </div>
```

Comment: That one didn't do the job. It still gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
model.Categories = new SelectList(_db.NewsCategories, "Id", "Name");
```

At this line you fill `Categories` property

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Categories, Model.SelectedCategories)
```

Here you trying create `select` with `Categories` name and `SelectedCategories` items

```
int id = int.Parse(newsModel.SelectedCategories.Single(f => f.Selected).Value);
```

Here you trying get selected item, BUT on form submit you only sending one number, not list. One of your `SelectList` must be `int`

Comment: I'm now sure what I should do with the one that is int - Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Xenoxsis Yes, your answer is correct. You add `SelectedCategoryId` and remove `SelectedCategories`, so you getting `id` for selected option.